# Neo4j/Rails 3.2.8 & Jruby 1.6.7.2 : First Build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, neo4j

I'm attempting to build my first Neo4j application on Rails and jRuby. Here is my gemfile...

https://gist.github.com/4087134

When I bundle I get this error: Could not find gem 'neo4j (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j.git (at master).
Source contains 'neo4j' at: 2.2.0

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Any reason you're pointing directly to the git repo instead of using rubygems.org?

Comment: Good question. An associate of mine has built a Neo4j app and showed me his Gemfile. I used his references.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to use 2.2.0 before it was released in October?

Comment: It was the Active Model ties with the specific repositories being pointed to. Once those two items were changed it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Bundler is not using jruby...It's looking for 'neo4j (>= 0) ruby'.
This happens to me when I forget to have RVM switch over to jruby. 
If you're not using RVM, you can use the --shebang option on bundler to use jruby. Like: 
bundle --shebang which jruby

Comment: I am using RVM and that is the error I get after I switch to jRuby and run bundler.

Comment: I think I know what's throwing the error. I started from a base rails app and not a Neo4j template behind it so it's trying to load Active Record and Neo4j. I will have a more positive answer when I get a chance to run it again tonight. I'll let you guys know.

Comment: Hm. yeah, you're probably going to do that to get the app running, but I'm not sure that would screw up the bundle. Try removing the :git parameters so that you're getting the 2.2.0 release and not pulling from the head. also, I think all you'll need (if you want to have a HA cluster)  is:   
gem 'neo4j'  
gem 'neo4j-advanced', '1.8.RC1'  
gem 'neo4j-enterprise', '1.8.RC1'     Otherwise, you can just have gem 'neo4j' if you're not needing HA. maybe that'll do it?

Comment: It was the Active Model ties with the specific repositories being pointed to. Once those two items were changed it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bundler to manage gems, be sure to use `bundle` to invoke your application with `jruby -S bundle exec`. My guess is that you are running `bundle` in your `$PATH`, which does not invoke `jruby` at all.